# Change route target dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a site administration tool created with MVC3 which has a route `{brand}/{controller}/{action}`. We now need to have two different controllers for different brands, a `SimpleProductController` and `Product2_0Controller`, because new sites will use "Product 2.0", while older sites will still use "Simple Product". What we now want to do is have `{brand}/Product/{action}` route to the appropriate controller, depending on the brand.

One way of doing it would be to create a `ProductController` which implements the forwarding behaviour, but I feel that would become messy quite quickly as it would have to implement all the actions of both controllers. Is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Another way would be to generate all the routes statically I suppose. Not very pretty either, but at least better than the forwarding controller, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add the version number into the route? This would then be extensible if Product 3.0 came along:

```
{brand}/{version}/{controller}/{action}
```

You could then choose your Area by convention.